# How to import the material.io Color Tool Palette generated scheme to Flutter / Android Studio?

Tags: flutter

I really like the tool here https://material.io/resources/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=0&primary.color=F5F5F5&secondary.color=FF3D00&primary.text.color=4E342E
Is there a way to import the generated colors.xml to Flutter?

Comment: There is no easy way to do it. What you can do instead is, create a your own custom Color class and add all the colors from the xml file as static variables and reference them from the app.

Comment: Thx Sudhanshu! Found this tool meanwhile, looks promising https://rxlabz.github.io/panache/#/

Comment: This tool looks cool. But it could also generate a lot of boilerplate. I just do it on my own to only keep things that I want. And I also try to keep the Colors file a bit lean. Thanks for the tool suggestion though.

Comment: Thanks Sudhanshu! Meanwhile, I created a feature request at Google Flutter. Wonder why they have not thought about such a feature so far. It is time to walk the talk :) https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57637#event-3355557452

Comment: We could also make a plugin for this together. We don't know when they will the development to support this feature.